# Dual-booting Fedora (already installed) and Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, dual-boot, manjaro

I use Fedora with GNOME... I wanted to dual-boot it with Manjaro KDE because I want to discover more, and because GNOME is pretty buggy...

What partitions should I create in the Manjaro Calamares installer?

Comment: Are you aware that you may also just change desktop environments within a given distro? It sounds as if it would suffice for you to just install KDE on fedora instead of getting a whole new distribution. It this correct?

Comment: @FelixJN I know that I could just install KDE Plasma on Fedora instead of dual-booting another distro, but I need Manjaro/Arch's benefits too

Comment: Then please specify where your problems are and what you have available. Do you have a free partition/drive available or do you need to shrink the size of fedora to make space? Where are you stuck, what information are you missing? Please be more on point and clearly name your problems otherwise you might not get a good answer (or none at all).

Comment: @FelixJN Yes, I will resize the Fedora partition... I just want to know what partition should I make for Manjaro

Comment: In what terms? Size, filesystem, mount points? Does your fedora have a separate data partition you want to share between the two? What total size do you plan for manjaro?

Comment: @FelixJN I have a 1TB SSD, 500GB for Fedora and 500GB for Manjaro,

Comment: [Thanks!] I would like this comment into an answer, with all the steps sliced out (if possible)

Comment: Transferred to answer. Hope this helps - feel free to ask for details. Please also update your question with more focus on the partitioning issue and what hardware you have available. It will make readers better understand if this matches their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main concern seems to be what partition setup to use. Nowadays 30GB is usually by far enough for a system for several years, if you do lots of programming with copious amounts of libraries or parallelly run many desktop environments, use 50GB for a distro.

Given your 1 TB drive, I would suggest the following: make partitions for the core system of each distribution and use the remaining part as shared data partition.

The shared data partition is for all data like photos, videos, programming projects, downloads, ... anything interesting for access from either distro. The interesting thing here is that you may change or reinstall a distro while keeping your data intact.

Additionally you might be interested in some swap space, a third OS partition (why not test a BSD system?), a partition for playing around (e.g. testing file systems like XFS or ReiserFS) or a separate partition for encrypted data.

Note that if you use a shared swap partition for several distros, you may face data loss if you boot distro B while distro A is hibernated! So for several hibernated systems, each would need its own swap.

Of course the EFI should not be forgotten on modern systems.

So a possible minimal setup could be (rounded):

```
1/2 GB EFI
50 GB fedora
50 GB manjaro
900 GB shared data
```

Or with some the above mentioned options and a bit less space per distro:

```
1/2 GB EFI
33 GB fedora
33 GB manjaro
33 GB BSD/solaris/...
8 GB swap (be aware of the hibernation limitation for shared swap!)
2 GB test partition
10 GB encrypted data
880 GB shared data
```

If you have the possibility, I'd suggest to get your data on an external drive. Then see if shrinking fedora is worth it for your or if doing the setup from scratch is better.

Note that the data partition best get its own mountpoint (e.g. `/data` -> define in `fstab`) and do **not** make it a shared `/home` partition: local config files may differ and only create headaches.

For ensuring that downloads don't cramp up your distro partition, you may very well just make the standard directories as soft links to the `/data` partition. Personally, I use such setup.